# JasperReports and Database Design Concept

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a fairly simple question concerning a design with a view for how reports would look like when the program is complete. I use *Java*, with *JasperReports* for my reporting needs.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but *JasperReports* does not make elements from different tables overlap to make sense, for example, in my case, I would like the the sales and receipt of an Item in a single report ordered by date (Sales and Receipts overlap). I have a sales table and a receipt table in the database.

The question is, should I redesign my database so that both sales and receipts are stored in the same table, or is there a way jasper reports can merge both tables and make reports overlap in a tabular form?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an SQL query, from which the table in jasper-reports will take it's data.
In this SQL, you can write a join that will get you the data from both of the tables.
So you can leave the design of your tables as it is now.